# Extension methods for MailMessage Bcc AddRange

Tags: c#, extension-methods, system.net.mail

When adding multiple recipients to a `MailMessage.BCC` there is no option for `AddRange()`. Only `MailMessage.Bcc.Add();`

Can this functionality be changed by an extension method? I'm a little lost at this point, any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing you are talking about the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage class, what you need is already provided by the MailAddressCollection.Add method (Bcc is of the MailAddressCollection type).

Just call Add method with multiple e-mail addresses separated by a comma character (",").

Check this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: +1 I did not see that overload to the `MailAddressCollection` class.

Answer (score 5):

`MailMessage.Bcc` is of type `MailAddressCollection`. This `MailAddressCollection` implements `ICollection<MailAddress>`. So what you can do, is write a generic `AddRange` extension method which applies to any `ICollection<T>`.

This will look like the following:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> target, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            target.Add(item);
        }   
    }
}
```

You can then use this like so:

```
var address1 = new MailAddress("abc@xyz.com");
var address2 = new MailAddress("wxy@hij.com");
message.Bcc.AddRange(new[] { address1, address2 });
```

Comment: This is great, I'm sorry I forgot to say though my list of emails are all of type string, I'd ideally not want to convert them to a MailAddress outside the Extension Method!

Comment: That's fine, you're probably going to be better off with @catalin-manoliu's solution :)